# Longest substring in alphabetical order Javascript

Tags: javascript

Seeing all the people talking about longest substring in alphabetical order in Python, I have decided to try it in JS.
The function should look for the longest substring inside a given string, where letters are ordered alphabetically.

Here is what I have:

```js
var s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

function substringChecker(s) {
 var longestSub = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var count = 0;
  var currSub = "";
  while((i+count)<=s.length){
   var curr = i+count;
   var next = curr+1;
   var prev = curr-1;
   if(curr !== s.length-1) {
    if(s[curr] <= s[next]){
     currSub += s[curr]
    } else {
     break;
    }
   } else {
    if(s[curr]>s[prev]) {
     currSub += s[curr];
    }
   }
  count++;
  }
  if(currSub.length >= longestSub.length) {
   longestSub = currSub;
  }
 };
 return longestSub;
}
var result = substringChecker(s);;
console.log(result);
```

The funny thing it works great for all test cases I can come up with, but this one. The result should be "beggh" but it is "begg" instead. Why is the h not showing up, what am I missing?

Comment: Which "all people" do you mean, can you share a link to that python topic? The only ones I found are from 2013.

Comment: WTH are you comparing the current character in that loop both to the previous and to the next character? You may want to try to simplify that.

Comment: The problem is that you are checking the next character if it is still in alphabetical order but store the current one, so you will always miss the last character of the longest string (*unless it ends on the last character of the original*). But @Oriol [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30967138) is a better approach altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm can be linear, I think you are overcomplicating it placing loops inside loops.

I would use something like

```js
function substringChecker(s) {
  var longestSub = "",
      length = 0,
      start = 0,
      prev = s[0];
  for (var i = 1; i <= s.length; ++i) {
    if(i == s.length || s[i] < prev) {
      if(length < i-start) {
        longestSub = s.substring(start, i);
        length = i-start;
      }
      start = i;
    }
    prev = s[i];
  };
  return longestSub;
}
document.write(substringChecker('azcbobobegghakl'));
```

Answer (score 0):

first I made list of A-z 
then check each letter and compare it with the next letter and save it in subString and...

```js
function longest(str) {
  //handle the case str is just one letter
  if (str.length === 1) return str;
   // create a list of alphabet A to Z
  const alphabets = [...Array(26)].map(_ => String.fromCharCode(i++), (i = 97));
  let longString = "";
  let subSting = "";
  for (let x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
    let char = str.charAt(x);
    const nextChar = str.charAt(x + 1);
    let charIndex = alphabets.findIndex(alphabet => alphabet === char);
    let nextCharIndex = alphabets.findIndex(alphabet => alphabet === nextChar);
    if (nextCharIndex >= charIndex) {
      subSting = subSting + nextChar;
    } else {
      if (!subSting.length) {
        subSting = subSting + char;
      }
      longString = subSting.length > longString.length ? subSting : longString;
      subSting = "";
    }
  }
  return longString;
}
console.log(longest("zyba"));
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the answer and add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: I add some comments and short description but technically you are checking each char of str with next char and if in alphabet order is bigger save in substring and continue to the end and